# Google Assistant - Raspberry pi as IoT device only (no voice control, just actions)

Tags: raspberry-pi, google-assistant-sdk

I cannot get a clear answer on this via Google (not sure I know what to Google), Basically I want to use a Pi as home control device via Google Assistant.

I have seen a few Google Assistant + Pi projects but they all include a mic and the users saying "OK, Google". However, there is no clear indication if the Google Assistant can still function without voice commands. In short, I want the Pi to be just an IoT device and use my phone as voice input.

I have also seen the Actions on Google page ( https://developers.google.com/actions/smarthome/ ). This looks a bit daunting and I am not sure if this is for Hobbyists or just open to Google partners.

Any clarification would be helpful.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The [smart home](https://developers.google.com/actions/smarthome/) platform seems to be designed to fit your needs in that you are able to remote control an IoT device like a Raspberry Pi from another Assistant surface instead of talking directly to the Pi.

If the documentation may appear to be a bit daunting, it may be useful to get started with a [sample Node.js](https://github.com/actions-on-google/smart-home-nodejs) project to see how the JSON requests and responses are formatted, or try the [smart home codelab](https://codelabs.developers.google.com/codelabs/smarthome-washer/) project to get more hands-on with building one of these projects and get an understanding of the platform.